# How to calculate luck factor based on bet winchance/result?

Tags: php, mysql, probability

I am working on a website where users can bet on events with variable win chance. One of the rquests is to display the "Luck factor" of a certain user, based on his bets.

Here is the definition of the Luck factor:

The luck percentage displayed shows how many bets you have won compared to how many you 'should' have won. For example, if you play 10 times with a 10% chance of winning and win two of the 10 bets, your luck will show as 200%, since you have won twice as many as you 'should' have. Bet size is not taken into account when calculating luck, so it is possible to have a luck less than 100% and still show a profit if your winning bets risked more than your losing bets.

Here is my (MySQL) database structure:

Table **bet**

Columns:

- winchance (0.01 - 99.99)
- win (true/false)

The application is written in php, but I am sure a pseudocode example would push me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, right, You can take the average of winning probability using mysql winchance column and real winning ratio, would be (number of wins / total number of bets). Given these two values, luck factor would be real ratio / winchance avg * 100.

For instance, avg win chance is 0.1 and real winning ratio, is 2 / 10 = 0.2, then luck factor is 0.2/0.1 * 100 = 200%. This shall be easily calculated with mysql inbuilt functions itself.